# Condition, if rewrite return 404 status, return another page

Tags: nginx

I have a rewrite for old unused subdomains 90% URL corresponds to both the primary and subdomain, but some url are unique to the subdomain.

How to make a condition, if the rewrite returns 404, then return a custom page.

```
if ($host ~* (sub1|sub2|sub3)\.mysite\.loc) {
  rewrite ^(.+)$ http://mysite.loc$1 permanent;
  location / {
    error_page 404 =301 http://mysite.loc/lost-sub;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), for example:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri @failover;
}

location @failover {
   proxy_pass http://failover;
}
```

In this case, if file not found instead of returning a `404` it will try the `location @failover`